# BeautifulSoup extract data from <script> with unicode

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, unicode, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a JSON in a script of an html page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36 OPR/64.0.3417.47",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "fr-FR,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
}

proxy = "http://stack:overflow@45.135.149.142:14758"

url = "https://www.seloger.com/list.htm?projects=2%2C5&types=2%2C1&natures=1%2C2%2C4&places=%5B%7Bci%3A60088%7D%5D&enterprise=0&qsVersion=1.0"
r = requests.get(url, proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy}, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    if "initialData" in script.text:
        data = script.text.split('JSON.parse("', 1)[1].split('");window["tags"]', 1)[0]
        json_data = json.loads(data)
```

And this error is returned:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

The problem is that \u0022 is not converted to a quotation mark " which triggers the json decoder error.

Also, whenever I print the code of the script, \u0022 is printed instead of ". I have already tried encoding and decoding in multiple formats before passing it to json.loads but nothing worked.

Th problem only comes when the code is parsed directly from the request response. I cannot replicate the issue. This code works as expected:

```
snippet = '''<script>
window["initialData"] = JSON.parse("{\u0022foo\u0022:\u0022bar\u0022,\u0022xxx\u0022:\u0022xyz\u0022}")
</script>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(snippet, 'html.parser')
for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    data = script.text.split('JSON.parse("')[1].split('")')[0]
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    print(json_data)
    # output : {'foo': 'bar', 'xxx': 'xyz'}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's with the lines which start with `//` ? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Comment: I updated the question with a minimal reproducible example

Comment: _I cannot replicate the issue._ That's going to be a problem, since it looks like we can't run the actual code which includes the parsing.

Comment: It's unlikely to be the issue, but you should use `BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')` instead of `BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')`. It's probably also worth isolating the JSON using regex, instead of repeatedly splitting.

Comment: Can I know where you can't replicate?

Comment: `proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy}`

Comment: These are proxies that I am using or the request would go through a few times only. I'm removing it from the question to make it more easily replicable

Comment: Yup, I got blocked, and I hadn't thought of writing the response to a file...

Comment: I tried both `r.content` and `r.text`. Same result

Comment: I'm going to update the code with the proxy I am temporary using to unblock. Thanks for your help

Comment: @EnricoMaria I've given an answer to you with the json data loaded and accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content you're trying to scrape includes unicode escape sequences which seem to actually be escaped themselves.

The solution I've found involves encoding and then decoding the string, although there might be a better way:

```py
data.encode("utf-8").decode("unicode-escape")
```

I also made some other tweaks to your code, particularly in how the data is parsed, seen in this snippet which I used as a demo/test:

```py
json_re = re.compile(r"window\[\"initialData\"] = JSON\.parse\(\"(.*)\"\);window\[\"tags\"]")

with open("../out/temp.html", 'rb') as file_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file_in.read(), 'lxml')

raw_data = ""
for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    if "initialData" in script.text:
        res_text = script.get_text(strip=True)
        raw_data = json_re.search(res_text).group(1)
        break

print(raw_data)
t_1 = raw_data.encode("utf-8")
print(t_1)

t_2 = t_1.decode("unicode-escape")
print(t_2)

t_3 = json.loads(t_2)
print(t_3)
```

Comment: `json_re.search(res_text)` outputs `NoneType` to me

Comment: @EnricoMaria Oh, that’s bad. Can you share the start and end of the JSON string you have?

Comment: `res_text` begins with `window["initialData"] = JSON.parse("{\u0022config\u0022:` and ends with `\u0022isPaginationDisplayed\u0022:false}}}");`
Then I get this error: 
`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-198-aa7f3e038ce7> in <module>
      9         res_text = script.get_text(strip=True)
     10         print(res_text)
---> 11         raw_data = json_re.search(res_text).group(1)
     12         print(raw_data)
     13         break

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: @EnricoMaria Is the rest of the code just like what I shared?

Comment: Yes I did copy paste. My html file is in `./temp.html` instead of `../out/temp.html`. I copied it from view-source of the link above.

Comment: @EnricoMaria Ah the file location shouldn’t make a difference, this is strange. What do you mean _copied it from_ ?

Comment: I opened the url of the code in Chrome (https://www.seloger.com/list.htm?projects.....) and did view-source, then saved it in a .html file

Comment: @EnricoMaria That’s probably it, try saving the parsed HTML you get from the request (aka the contents of `soup`).

Comment: Should I save the content of soup or r.text instead?

Comment: @EnricoMaria Soup.

Comment: `t_2` looks good. I concatenated them with `t_0 = raw_data.encode("utf-8").decode("unicode-escape")` and it looks good. Now, why does it work only if we save it in a file?

Comment: @EnricoMaria Oh, it should work on the actual website too, I just ran my tests on a local file so as not to spam the site.

Comment: Actually it does. Thank you, this answer solved the issue for me! Marked as solution. @AMC

Comment: @EnricoMaria I'm glad it works, I will write up an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a regex (not the best way), but this worked for me:

```
import requests,json,re
proxy='http://stack:overflow@45.135.149.142:14758'
url='https://www.seloger.com/list.htm?projects=2%2C5&types=2%2C1&natures=1%2C2%2C4&places=%5B%7Bci%3A60088%7D%5D&enterprise=0&qsVersion=1.0'
r = requests.get(url, proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy})
json_data = json.loads(json.loads('"' + re.search(r'JSON\.parse\("(.+)"\);w', r.text).group(1) + '"')) # note it needs to be double wrapped
json_data.keys()
# dict_keys(['cards', 'navigation', 'SEO', 'tracking', 'adverts', 'bookmarks', 'failure', 'engine'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I may go for this one if I can't fix it with encodings

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the splitting step, but I had similar problems with json and encodings. Try to recode the response.text with 'utf-8' or 'latin'. Some times it worked for me.
Hope it helps!